# Best way of calling a long running process asynchronously in .net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am trying to call a long running task from web api like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        await Task.Run(()=>_report.TestFunctionAsync());
        
        return Accepted();

    }
```

And this is the task

```
    public async Task TestFunctionAsync()
    {
        ProcessStatus = 0;
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        ProcessStatus = 1;//wrting to DB
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        ProcessStatus = 2;//Fetching from Excel
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        ProcessStatus = 3;//Processing
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50));
        ProcessStatus = 9;//Finished
    }
```

But when googling I found from UI perspective, its async and UI never be blocked. But its not the correct way.

So please suggest a better way of implementing this. Also is there is any way to understand what is the status of the asyn task (using the ProcessStatus property)

Comment: Is your question "how do I call a long-running task from ASP.NET web API without blocking the UI?"

Comment: OK, start by reading [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html).  It is a series of posts that explains in detail how to do what you're asking, and it does it in a way that is durable, reliable, and ASP.NET MVC friendly.

Comment: Yes, thats true.. My question is how to call a long running task from web api without blocking ui

Comment: Read the series of articles I linked.

Comment: `Its async and UI never be blocked`  you have one main thread that is responsible for dispatching requests (although Kestrel is really good with it so the net effects are a lot less pronounced than in the old ASP.Net on IIS). So avoiding blocking it is the same priority for a web dev as it is for the Desktop dev in regards to UI thread.

Correct way is to host it in a different application requests to which are dispatch via some sort of a queue. Specifics depend a lot on your environment, hosting options, budget etc

Comment: here is a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56476608/1426685

Answer (score 3):

Since ASP.NET MVC does not itself provide the ability to process long-running tasks, you have to create an external solution.

1. [Create a Durable Queue](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-2-durable-queues.html) in which to place your requests for long-running operations.  RabbitMQ as an example.  Alternatively, write your requests to a *requests* table in your data store/database.
2. [Create a Backend Service](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-3-backend-processor.html) to execute your long-running tasks.  It should read the requests from your Durable Queue or database table, and act on them accordingly.  This can be a Windows Service, Linux Daemon or AWS Lambda, etc.
3. [Create a notification mechanism](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-4-retrieve-results.html) so that the UI can be notified when the task completes, such as a web socket connection or polling.  Or, provide an endpoint on the ASP.NET Web API that allows your web page to retrieve task status.

Comment: your answer "asp.net does not support long-running tasks" as it is, is just wrong. you suggested a solution -- well, the approach is good and widely used, but that's still one of the possible approaches. and you do not answer the original question. the other answer (below atm) is more appropriate

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft suggests the following options in [ASP.NET Core Performance Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-6.0) docs:

- Handle long-running requests with [background services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). In ASP.NET Core, background tasks can be implemented as hosted services. A hosted service class with background task logic that implements the IHostedService interface.
- Also, you can use an [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) to complete work out-of-process. This scenario is especially beneficial for CPU-intensive tasks.
- To notify your clients using real-time communication options, such as [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0), to communicate with clients asynchronously.